# How to notify worker thread that UI is modified using Handler.Post()?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a worker thread and occasionally i send updates to the UI Thread using `Handler.Post()`. In some cases i need worker thread to wait until `Handler.Post()` executed on UI Thread **and** the view is modified and **after** UI thread is modified, notify the worker Thread to go on...
here is my simple worker thread:

```
workerThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Step1: which works ok
                ActionModeButton.performClick();
            }
        }

        //Step2: returns null pointer exception because ActionMode
        //is not yet created and R.id.select_recording is an
        //ActionMode button if I put Thread.sleep(1000); here it
        //will work fine.
        final View selectRecording = getActivity()
                .findViewById(R.id.select_recording);
        selectRecording.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                selectRecording.performClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
workerThread.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using synchronized block with wait and notify

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Object lock = new Object();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        boolean completed = false;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        //Do some stuff on ui thread 

                        completed = true;
                        lock.notifyAll();                            
                    }
                }
            });

            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                  if(!completed)
                    lock.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Be careful with this because it's not thread safe. There is a chance that post will run before the lock.wait(). If this happens, runnable with acquire the lock, do some stuff, and notify the lock. Then, at a later time, the lock.wait() will run and wait forever. An extra 'isCompleted' boolean, set in the synchronized, and checked before the lock will solve this.

Comment: Yes i agree, there is a possibility that runnable post will be executed before lock.wait() is called. Update answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `Semaphore` for that?

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
  // ... do something here
  semaphore.release();
});
semaphore.acquire();
```

The `Semaphore` start with `0` permit. The thread will block on `semaphore.acquire()` until `semaphore.release()` (which will add a permit) is called.