# Is this a correct way to pause thread until callback?

Tags: java, android

I want to pause and start thread untill variable standby.
But wait() and notify() is not work for me.
Is this a collect way to pause thread?

```
private boolean _threadIsWaiting = true;
private Object  _specialObjectFromHttp;

public void methodToUse() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        getParamsFromHttp();

        while (_threadIsWaiting) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        convertObject(_specialObjectFromHttp);

    )};
}

// Callback method (Thread wait for this.)
private void getParamsFromHttpCallBack(Object result) {
    _specialObjectFromHttp = result;
    _threadIsWaiting = false;
}
```

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732101/how-to-notify-worker-thread-that-ui-is-modified-using-handler-post/16732303#16732303

Comment: "But wait() and notify() is not work for me." - it would be helpful if you explained why as this would be the standard approach.

Comment: Take a look at CountDownLatch. It'll do the trick perfectly for you. Instantiate it with value 1, call await() in run, call countDown in getParamsFromHttpBack.

Comment: I understood that my approach is not suitable way to do this.
And I also understood there are some ways to do this. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object to wait on, and call notify on it. I believe that to be the better approach (Actually, it is almost always better to utilize such a mechanism instead of sleeping and bool checking).

```java
private Object  _specialObjectFromHttp;

public void methodToUse() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        getParamsFromHttp();
        _specialObjectFromHttp.wait();
    )};
}

// Callback method (Thread wait for this.)
private void getParamsFromHttpCallBack(Object result) {
    _specialObjectFromHttp = result;
    _specialObjectFromHttp.notifyAll();
}
```

In this case it seems plausible to just use the object that is being used in that control flow anyways, but you could also just add another object that has no purpose other than being waited for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SynchronousQueue this will block until the information you need is provided. So in one thread call take, this will wait for a put on a different thread.
Both methods are blocking and no manual syncing is needed.